# Packet size (mBytesPerPacket) or the bitrate for AAC files in Core Audio

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio, audio-processing, bitrate

I want to configure a `AudioStreamBasicDescription` with **constant bit rate** AAC type.

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription clientFormat = {0};
clientFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.0;
clientFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
clientFormat.mFormatFlags        = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Main;
clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 2;
clientFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 0;
clientFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 0;
clientFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1024;
clientFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 0;
clientFormat.mReserved           = 0;
```

For `mBytesPerPacket`the Apple documentation says:

> The number of bytes in a packet of audio data. To indicate variable
>   packet size, set this field to 0. For a format that uses variable
>   packet size, specify the size of each packet using an
>   AudioStreamPacketDescription structure.

I want to have it as a constant, so I have to plug there a non-zero value (the desired size), but everything besides 0 fails.

Any help on this?

Comment: How does it fail? Leave `mBytesPerPacket` as 0. AAC _does_ have variable packet sizes.

Comment: You are right @RhythmicFistman. It was my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that we can set codec properties right on the AudioConverter.

So I did:

```
AudioConverterSetProperty(acRef, kAudioCodecPropertyBitRateControlMode,
                                                  sizeof(control_mode), &control_mode);

AudioConverterSetProperty(acRef, kAudioCodecPropertyCurrentTargetBitRate,
                                                  sizeof(_bitRate), &_bitRate);
```